# Handling working of PHP API key on webpage

Tags: php, api

i m building a phpapi and in this api will be giving my clients API key generated for each client.
So basically my client will be sending **client id,his personal data(to be stored in DB) & an API key** to my **api.php** page and this API key will be placed in a **hidden** field on clients form.
Now my doubt here is that this key can be seen by anyone if they view page source...
So how can i prevent key from being not seen so that no other clients can use it for them..

OR

Is there any other way to place API key on form so it cannot be seen and use securely..

Answer (score 0):

Every data you send to your client can be viewed by him and others (Sniffers ;) ).

The only way to make the communication between him and you really secure is to use a HTTPS-Connection (=> SSL-Certificate!). Then it is nearly impossible for others to see the API-Key but the client himself will be able to see it in the source-code. If the client's pc has to know the key then the client will be always able to view it.

Comment: i strongly believe you..but any can u suggest me some way other than HTTPS? is the way i shown above is correct?

Comment: Its always going to be known to every client who is assigned that APIkey but i want to secure it from others and is it proper way to use hidden field for APIKEY or i can do something else?

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to use php sessions? This way the api key stays on the server and coupled with https would provide great security.

Comment: Its like users will login in ABC.com and ABC.com is my api's client..so all users longing at abc.com can use this API to add there details..